# Expected Parcelable for result for camera Intent

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult

I am making a camera intent and storing the snapshot using the activity result, this is my code:

```java
File imageFolder=new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(),"Cam/" + form);
imageFolder.mkdirs();
String random= UUID.randomUUID().toString();
String filename = random + ".jpg";
TakenImage =  imageFolder + "/" + filename;
Intent camera=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,TakenImage);
activityResultCamera.launch(camera);
```

But I get this error on the last line:

> Key output expected Parcelable but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value  was returned.
>
> Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable

Camera is an Intent, I also declared ActivityResultLauncher as Intent

```java
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultCamera = registerForActivityResult(...
```

So, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXTRA_OUTPUT` needs to be:

- A `Uri`...
- With a scheme of `content`

You have:

- A `String`...
- That is a filesystem path that other apps cannot access on Android 10+

Use `FileProvider` to get a `Uri` that points to your desired location, and use that `Uri` in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Comment: Oh, you are totally right, for others having this issue: `Uri uriImage = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.myapp.provider", image);`, and then: `camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uriImage);`